# JQuery Mobile / Rho listview automatically changes to dialog

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, dialog, rhomobile

I have a mobile page with a listview.  If the contents of the list are longer then the mobile viewport, the listview automatically changes to a dialog.  If the list fits inside the viewport it says as a listview.  (not sure if the JQuery behaviour or something in Rho)  At any rate, the change event is not working when in dialog mode.  Anyone experience this before?

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#coltreg-show-page', function(event) {
var $activePage = $.mobile.activePage

// bind for term select change
var $coltSessions = $activePage.find('select#coltsessions')
$coltSessions.bind('change', function() {
    var evId = $(this).val()
    loadDetails( { evId: evId } )
})


//$leftArrow = $activePage.find('a#left-arrow')
//$leftArrow.bind('click', function() {
//    var termId = $selectTerm.val()
//    loadGrades( { termId: termId, previousTerm: true } )
//})
//$rightArrow = $activePage.find('a#right-arrow')
//$rightArrow.bind('click', function() {
//    var termId = $selectTerm.val()
//    loadGrades( { termId: termId, nextTerm: true } )
//})

// load if grades aren't already there
var $regsesList = $activePage.find('ul#regses-list')
if ( $regsesList.children().size() > 1 ) return

var evId = $coltSessions.val()
loadDetails( { evId: evId } )
})


function loadDetails(argMap) {
argMap = argMap || {}
argMap.evId = argMap.evId || null
//argMap.previousTerm = argMap.previousTerm || false
//argMap.nextTerm = argMap.nextTerm || false
var $activePage = $.mobile.activePage

$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()

var requestUrl = "/app/Coltreg/async_coltreg"
var requestData = {}
if ( argMap.evId ) requestData['evId'] = argMap.evId
//requestData['previousTerm'] = argMap.previousTerm
//requestData['nextTerm'] = argMap.nextTerm
loadDetailsRequest(requestUrl, requestData)
}


function loadDetailsRequest(requestUrl, requestData) {
var $activePage = $.mobile.activePage
var $regsesList = $activePage.find('ul#regses-list')
$.get(requestUrl, requestData, function(result){
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()
    $regsesList.find('li#eid').remove()
    $regsesList.append(result)
    $regsesList.listview("refresh").trigger("updatelayout")
})    
}
```

The erb page:

```
<div data-role="content">
                             <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" id="regses-list">
                                 <li id="regses-selector" class="sessionNav">
                                     <div class="sn-btn">
                                         <ul>
                                             <li></li>
                                             <li class="centerLink">
                                                 <select name="coltsessions" id="coltsessions" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-iconpos="none" data-inline="true" data-native-menu="false">
                                                     <%
                                                         ev = get_mnth_events
                                                             ev.each do |e|
                                                     %>
                                                                 <option value="<%= e['evntid'] %>">
                                                                     <%= e['evntname'] %>
                                                                 </option>
                                                     <%
                                                         end
                                                     %>
                                                 </select>
                                             </li>
                                             <li></li>
                                         </ul>
                                     </div>
                                 </li>

                             </ul>
                         </div><!-- /content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is jQuery Mobile behavior. You can see it in action in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5rc7/).
If it shows as a regular listview in the fiddle, slide down the 'Result' box to make it smaller and see the dialog appear.

```
<select data-native-menu="false">
  <option>text</option>    
  <option>text</option>
  <option>text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160479/prevent-dialog-view-for-jquerymobile-multi-select-control-with-large-list-of-opt